# UNITTEST in Python is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyspark

I took example from python website and tried to run in community.databricks.com platform. I am getting Attribute error. Please advise

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '41750'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-88-3ccf7d7a57bd> in <module>()
     18 
     19 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 20     unittest.main()

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in __init__(self, module, defaultTest, argv, testRunner, testLoader, exit, verbosity, failfast, catchbreak, buffer)
     92         self.testLoader = testLoader
     93         self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])
---> 94         self.parseArgs(argv)
     95         self.runTests()
     96 

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in parseArgs(self, argv)
    147             else:
    148                 self.testNames = (self.defaultTest,)
--> 149             self.createTests()
    150         except getopt.error, msg:
    151             self.usageExit(msg)

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in createTests(self)
    156         else:
    157             self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
--> 158                                                            self.module)
    159 
    160     def _do_discovery(self, argv, Loader=None):

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc in loadTestsFromNames(self, names, module)
    128         of string specifiers. See 'loadTestsFromName()'.
    129         """
--> 130         suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
    131         return self.suiteClass(suites)
    132 

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc in loadTestsFromName(self, name, module)
     98         obj = module
     99         for part in parts:
--> 100             parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
    101 
    102         if isinstance(obj, types.ModuleType):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '41750'
```

Comment: From what folders and files and how do run the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

Comment: Any other way to invoke all the functions in that class. Instead of calling unittest.main() ??

Comment: you can use this instead of that, suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestStringMethods)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

Comment: if did not work then remove  ' if __name__ == '__main__': ' line too

Comment: It ran fine but assertion error is not coming if i give self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOOD')

Comment: you can use TRY CATCH like this for showing error,  try:
           self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOOD') 
        except AssertionError as e:
            print(e)

Comment: It worked i gave unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=sys.stderr,verbosity=2).run(suite)